# Xdebug return null for mysqli query in php

Tags: php, mysqli, xdebug, netbeans-7

I am trying to debug mysqli SELECT query on PHP 5.3.17 with Xdebug 2.2.1 Remote debugging
on Netbeans (windows 7) and debian squeeze remote server.

the code like that:

(it's a singleton)

```
$RawData = Database::call()->query($query);
```

and when i run debug, hover the mouse on RawData variable show me:

```
mysqli_result object {
  current_field => null
  field_count => null
  lengths => null
  num_rows => null
  type => null
}
```

Variable view tab show nothing 
(No error on /etc/php5/xdebug.log)

However when i run the script without debug, printing out results, the query returned correct values.

i sow similar question on  http://bugs.xdebug.org/view.php?id=881 but it occurs in different query result, php version, no remote server, and I'm not used var_dump.

what am i missing?

**EDIT**:
mysql query need "mysql_fetch" to view the result.

Comment: I don't understand your issue. The example you give looks OK IMHO.

Comment: thank's man you are right, I forgot that mysql query need "mysql_fetch" to view the result.
but there is situation that I get result  (not null)  in mysqli_result object {
  current_field => null
  field_count => null
  lengths => null
  num_rows => null
  type => null
} ?

Comment: This might be by xdebug itself. IIRC the mysqli objects are somewhat specific, so they might not be fully passed to your debugging environment because otherwise the code would break. If you need to inspect them, one trick would be to `json_encode` them to another variable first and then look into that json string.

Comment: Please add the additional information to your question.